# Email to students after completing course

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Iam new to moodle, We are using "single activity format" type courses where we add a scorm package into the course. I need to send the "congratulations" mail to students after completing the course, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

A notification is already sent when a student completes a course

But you will need to ensure that course completion is enabled for the course

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Course_completion

When a student completes a course, this notification will be sent

```
$string['coursecompletedmessage'] = '<p>Congratulations!</p><p>You have completed the course <a href="{$a->courselink}">{$a->coursename}</a>.</p>';
```

Check the message settings to see where the message is sent, depends on your admin but emails may have been switched off

Go to Site admin > General > Messaging > Notification settings

Or direct to `/admin/message.php`

Search on the page for "course completed" and check if email is enabled

You can also customise the message text via

Site admin > Language > Language customisation > [choose language]

Select `completion.php` for the component and enter `coursecompletedmessage` for the string identifier and click "show strings"

You can enter your own text in the "local customisation" box

Note : The course completion and sending notifications depends on cron being run. If you are testing this locally, you will probably need to run cron manually

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Cron

EDIT

You'll need to create a local plugin that responds to the course completed event

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/local

At a minimum, the local plugin requires these 2 files

```
/local/completionemail/version.php
/local/completionemail/lang/en/local_completionemail.php
```

Then create an observer to respond to the event

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API#Event_observers

In `/local/completionemail/db/events.php` something like

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\course_completed',
        'callback'  => 'local_completionemail_observer::course_completed',
    ),
);
```

In `/local/completionemail/classes/observer.php` something like

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class local_completionemail_observer {

    /**
     * Triggered when 'course_completed' event is triggered.
     *
     * @param \core\event\course_completed $event
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function course_completed(\core\event\course_completed $event) {
        $userid = $event->relateduserid;
        $courseid = $event->courseid;

        // Your email code here

        return true;

    }
}
```

Replace `completionemail` with your chosen plugin name

Technically, you should use the message api to send messages, but this will get you started

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Message_API

Comment: Hi, emails were switched off in my site. If i have to send a mail to students i have to do it through coding. Now, is there any way to achieve the above requirement.

Comment: Updated the answer for sending an email using an observer

Comment: How would you modify this to send the email a couple of weeks after they completed?

Comment: @frumbert You could use an adhoc task with the `set_next_run_time()` method  https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API#Set_a_task_to_run_at_a_future_time - there's an example in an observer here `/mod/quiz/report/statistics/classes/event/observer/attempt_submitted.php`